# Discretization of PDE-system (by lattices) - understanding the dimensions 1 and 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, partial-differential-equations

Consider the system
$$
\varepsilon\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=F(u,v)+\varepsilon^2\,\Delta u,\\\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=G(u,v)+\varepsilon^2\lambda\,\Delta v.
$$

Now, replace the continuous space variable $(x,y)$ by $(x_i,y_i)=(ih,jh)$ and the Laplace operator by $h^{-2}Du_{ij}$ where
$$
Du_{ij}=(u_{i-1,j}+u_{i,j-1}+u_{i+1,j}+u_{i,j+1}-4u_{i,j}).
$$
Here, $u(ih,jh)=u_{i,j}$.

Obviously, this is a discretization by use of a 2-dim-lattice.

We are now searching for approximative solutions
$$
(u_{i,j},v_{i,j}).
$$

I guess that both $u_{i,j}$ and $v_{i,j}$ are real-valued, so $(u_{i,j},v_{i,j})\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

My question only concerns the dimension of the phase portrait:

Will the phase portrait be a surface in three dimensions? I try to imagine it and think we first give a lattice point $(ih,jh)$ the real value $u_{i,j}$ and then, the same with another lattice (see picture) such that we get a point in the 3-dim space?

Picture: Let the red points be $(i,j)$, i.e. h=1, then $(u_{i,j},v_{i,j})$ is the brown point?

[image]

Moreoever, the one-dimensional case shall arise when the data is independent of one of the space variables. Does this mean thatthe one-dimensional case is just

[image]

where the red points are $i$ and $j$, i.e. again h=1, and the brwon point is $(u_i,v_i)$?

Comment: "My question only concerns the dimension of the phase portrait:" - "Phase portrait" of *what*?

Comment: phase portrait of the discretized/ approximating system resp. solution

Comment: If you use the method of lines and have $n+1$ points along $x$-axis and $m+1$ points along $y$ axis then the dimension of the corresponding phase portrait is $n-1\times m-1$.

Comment: Methods of lines? n+1 resp. m+1 point?

Comment: Ok, my suggestion would be to start with googling the definition of "phase portrait"

Comment: I know what a phase portrait is!!

Comment: My problem is just (in the 2d-lattice case) both uij and vjj give each grid point a real number, so for each grid point (ih,jh) we have a tuple in R^2. But how to draw that?

Comment: Or do i think wrongly and the phase portrait simply consists of trajectories in R^2 and the x-axis is uij and the y-axis is vij? - A phase portrait does not show the grid points and its values but only the possible values?